# Rails postgresql. Collision of two operations

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've got this shop-like application (Rails 3.2 + Postgresql), where two of my resources/tables are `User`s, and `Operation`s. It has the following characteristics:

- Amongst other attributes, `User`s have a certain `:credit` at each moment in time.
- `Operation`s represent either:

  1. A purchase of a **product** (whose price is deduced from the `User`'s credit who purchased it).
  2. A purchase of **credit** ( the amount of which is added to the `User`'s credit).
- Each `Operation` stores:

  1. `:precredit` - The credit the User had before the `Operation`.
  2. `:postcredit` - The final credit after the `Operation`.
  3. `:price` - The amount of money involved, whether it's positive or negative.

There was a problem with two `Operation` since they happened exactly at the same second ( My guess is that there was an internet problem for a while and then both queries were executed at the same second, see below).

This is the *sorted* sequence of operations by `created_at`(**credit** operations *add* and **product** operation *subtract* from the credit):

1. **Category**:credit  **Precredit**:2.9  **Price**:30.0  **Postcredit**:32.9  **Created_at**:16:34:02
2. **Category**:product  **Precredit**:32.9  **Price**:30.0  **Postcredit**:2.9  **Created_at**:16:42:06
3. **Category**:credit  **Precredit**:32.9  **Price**:5.0  **Postcredit**:37.9  **Created_at**:16:42:06
4. **Category**:product  **Precredit**:37.9  **Price**:4.0  **Postcredit**:33.9  **Created_at**:16:45:24

As one can see, `Operation#3` should have a `precredit = 2.9`, which is the `postcredit` of `Operation#2`. However, the result of `Operation#2` is not taken into account when `Operation#3` is executed.

Ideally I would have:

1. **Category**:credit  **Precredit**:2.9  **Price**:30.0  **Postcredit**:32.9  **Created_at**:16:34:02
2. **Category**:product  **Precredit**:32.9  **Price**:30.0  **Postcredit**:2.9  **Created_at**:16:42:06
3. **Category**:credit  **Precredit**:2.9  **Price**:5.0  **Postcredit**:-2.1  **Created_at**:16:42:06

Note that `Operation#3` would've raised an error due to `enough_balance?`-type validations resulting in `false`.

**Questions**

- Any ideas regarding how this might have happened?
- How can this type of collisions be avoided?

Comment: Sounds like read-modify-write race conditions. See an article I wrote on it recently: http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-read-modify-write-cycles/

Comment: That's an excellent article, informative and brief, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you're creating the operations, but this kind of situation can happen in concurrent environments, consider the next example:

- Process A: gets the User object to obtain the current credit (equal to precredit)
- Process B: gets the User object to obtain the current credit (at this point both have the same value)
- Process A: calculates the postcredit (precredit +/- value)
- Process B: calculates the postcredit
- Process B: saves the record
- Process A: saves the record

Even if the record in process A and the record in process B are not saved in the exact same millisecond (which is more unlikely), they still save both records with the same precredit, and this depends on how did they calculate this value. This is a common problem in operating systems and its solved with a 'Lock' ([Peterson's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm),[Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(computer_science)))

Now, Rails provides a mechanism for achieving this, I recommend you take a look at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html, the object you'll want to lock will probably be the user.